# Cforms II. Sender is unknown in user mail notification letter

Tags: wordpress, email

I am using [Cforms 2](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) plugin in my wordpress site. User fills the form and gets notification on his e-mail.
Problem: User gets the mail notification letter **from Unknown sender**. I need to set my **site's name** in this field. 
I have read [FAQ](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-forum/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions-faqs/page-1/). There is simullar question, but i guess it's for the Admin mail notification. In control panel of plugin there is no option for From field for User mail notification. And also I have asked this question on official site, but my question is still on "Awaiting Moderation" state.

Answer (score 0):

In the Form Settings, under Admin Email Messages, did you set that to your email?

Comment: I set for "From email address" as my sites name and for receiver I set email of my site. But this settings are for Admin Email Message. I need for user email message. In the User email message settings there is no "email" option.

Comment: Instead of having that set as your sites name have it set to your email address. This is the settings for the confirmation/response email sent to the user and the admin

Comment: Yeah that's works. But I need my site name to be shown in mail message's FROM field.

Comment: I did. Same "Unknown sender". But I need Admin mail too, so I can't turn it off.

Comment: It doesn't look like it can do that. I've looked around at different ways to set the settings but don't see anything to have it have your site name as the sender
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvB5h9hH8kY

Comment: Sad... What do you think, is it possible to hard-code this in php files of plugin?

Comment: I'm sure that there is a way to modify the code, but I wouldn't know what to do with that. http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-forum/troubleshooting/from-email-address-problem/
there was a little info on here that looks similar to what you want